# How to plot the derivative of a piecewise discontinuous function (by excluding discontinuity points)?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, piecewise, discontinuity

With the following code I am trying to get a plot for the derivative of the ftot1 function, which is a piecewise discontinuous function defined as the sum of other two piecewise discontinuous functions (fd and fo), but I receive an error and a blank plot.

```
td = 2; to = 2; T = 10; sld = 1; slo = 1;
fd[tstar_, x_ ] := 
  If[tstar < td, 0, 
   Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= x < td}, {sld*x, td <= x < tstar} , {sld*tstar,
       tstar <= x <= T}}]];
fo[tstar_ , x_] := 
  If[T - tstar < to, 0, 
   Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= x < tstar + to}, {slo*(x - tstar), 
      tstar + to <= x <= T}}]];
ftot1[tstar_, x_] = fd[tstar, x] + fo[tstar , x];
Plot[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T, {tstar, 0, T}, 
  Exclusions -> {tstar == td, tstar == T - to}, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]];
D[PiecewiseExpand[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T], tstar]
Limit[D[PiecewiseExpand[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T], tstar], 
 tstar -> td]
Limit[D[PiecewiseExpand[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T], tstar], 
 tstar -> to]
Limit[D[PiecewiseExpand[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T], tstar], tstar -> T]
Plot[D[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T, tstar], {tstar, 0, T}, 
 Exclusions -> {tstar == td, tstar == T - to}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

I am trying to deal with the discontinuity points, which are responsible for the failure of the Plot function I think. I have three discontinuity points (at td, to and T). I have tried to play with the range of the discontinuities (changing the equality sign) but nothing changes.

Comment: Add `Evaluate`. `Plot[D[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T, tstar] // Evaluate, {tstar, 0, T}, 
 Exclusions -> {tstar == td, tstar == T - to}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]`

Answer (score 1):

I have just seen that @cvgmt has given you a solution. Here is mine which is along the same lines.

```
td = 2; to = 2; T = 10; sld = 1; slo = 1;
fd[tstar_, x_] := 
  If[tstar < td, 0, 
   Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= x < td}, {sld*x, td <= x < tstar}, {sld*tstar, 
      tstar <= x <= T}}]];

fo[tstar_, x_] := 
  If[T - tstar < to, 0, 
   Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= x < tstar + to}, {slo*(x - tstar), 
      tstar + to <= x <= T}}]];

ftot1[tstar_, x_] = fd[tstar, x] + fo[tstar, x];

Plot[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T, {tstar, -1, T + 1}, 
 Exclusions -> {tstar == td, tstar == T - to}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image]

When you take the derivative you need to define a new function

```
    ClearAll[dt]; 
    dt[tstar_] := 
     Evaluate[D[PiecewiseExpand[ftot1[tstar, x] /. x -> T], tstar]]
Plot[dt[t], {t, -1, 12},
 Exclusions -> {tstar == td, tstar == T - to}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image]

This does not give you the nice exclusions probably because a point is not evaluated at the discontinuities. If you wish to show the exclusions something like the following will work

```
Show[
 Plot[dt[t], {t, -1, 2}],
 Plot[dt[t], {t, 2, 8}],
 Plot[dt[t], {t, 8, 10}],
 Plot[dt[t], {t, 10, 12}],
 Graphics[{Red, Dashing[{0.01, 0.01}], Line[{{2, -1}, {2, 0}}], 
   Line[{{8, 0}, {8, 1}}],
   Line[{{10, 1}, {10, 0}}]}],
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 12}, All}
 ]
```

[image]

However, I am not clear if it is just a plot you want. Also, the above could be automated but it was easier to use numbers rather than symbols.